# How to represent JOIN result as a plain rows? Collections, cursors?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a simple example (SQL is below) of what I mean ( For ex. in PL/SQL Developer it's simple to visualize).
So we have main-entity table and related main-entity-details, 1..N relations is possible.
We have an java-application which should request joined result of data of similar structure with stored procedure.
On the java side Hibernate technology is used.

Of course I can just return a cursor with result of JOIN operation. But necessarily we'll be dealing with duplicates,
just imagine how many they could be if ther are many main-entity-detail tables.

```
WITH main_table as (
  select 1 as id , 'property 1' as property from dual
  union all 
  select 2 as id , 'property 2' as property from dual
), 
details_table as(
  select 1 as main_table_id , 'value 1' as val from dual
  union all
  select 2 as main_table_id , 'value 12' as val from dual
  union all
  select 2 as main_table_id , 'value 13' as val from dual
)
select mt.id
     , mt.property
     , cursor (select main_table_id, val from details_table where main_table_id = mt.id)
  from main_table mt
```

Is it possible to pass result (as in my example) like

```
1. <id>, <main_property>, <cursor_with_details1>, <cursor_with_details2>
```

or maybe

```
2. <id>, <main_property>, <collection_with_details1>, <collection_with_details2>
```

Or somehow else? What the best practices are? I believe there is a way to represent results in the way closest to java objects, which can have rather complex hierarchical structure.

I've implemented the 1st approach as:

```
create or replace function fn_complicated_cursor return sys_refcursor
  is
  v_ret_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    open  v_ret_cur 
     for  WITH main_table as (
            select 1 as id , 'property 1' as property from dual
            union all 
            select 2 as id , 'property 2' as property from dual
          ), 
          details_table as(
            select 1 as main_table_id , 'value 1' as val from dual
            union all
            select 2 as main_table_id , 'value 12' as val from dual
            union all
            select 2 as main_table_id , 'value 13' as val from dual
          )
          select mt.id
               , mt.property
               , cursor (select main_table_id, val 
                           from details_table 
                          where main_table_id = mt.id)
            from main_table mt;
    return v_ret_cur;    
end fn_complicated_cursor;
```

Comment: What's wrong with displaying so-called "duplicate" rows? Especially when they're not duplicated, as with your example main and details tables. I guess what you really mean is that you don't want repeated values appearing in the results? If so, I'd stick with your implementation of using the cursor to get the values in one column.

Comment: I have never used it, but you can look at Object Views 'Using Nested Tables and Varrays in Object Views' https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjvew.htm

Comment: Thanks guys! I will write about the results, but for now, article advised by @Mottor showed me CAST(MULTISET()) construction - it gives the other way to return table data in a field, as a collection.